# How to get Latest value of row in Cursor result set in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I am using Cursor for some operation on same table which I used in Select statement of Cursor as below,

```
CREATE TABLE #nsn (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
,Val1 Varchar(MAx)
,Val2 Varchar(MAx)
)

INSERT INTO #nsn(Val1,VAl2) select 'A1','A2'
INSERT INTO #nsn(Val1,VAl2) select 'B1','B2'
INSERT INTO #nsn(Val1,VAl2) select 'C1','C2'
INSERT INTO #nsn(Val1,VAl2) select 'D1','D2'
INSERT INTO #nsn(Val1,VAl2) select 'E1','F2'

SELECT * From #nsn
ID  Val1    VAl2
1|  A1  |   A2
2|  B1  |   B2
3|  C1  |   C2
4|  D1  |   D2
5|  E1  |   F2
```

use cursor to update Val2 column,

```
DECLARE @ID INT 
        ,@Val1 Varchar(MAx)
        ,@Val2 Varchar(MAx)

DECLARE cursor_Latest CURSOR
FOR SELECT  ID,Val1,Val2
    FROM    #nsn 
    ORder by 1 asc
OPEN cursor_Latest
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_Latest INTO  @ID , @Val1 ,@Val2
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
BEGIN
    UPDATE #nsn
    SET Val2 = Val2 +'-'+ @Val1 +'-'+@Val2
    WHERE ID = @ID+1

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_Latest INTO  @ID , @Val1 ,@Val2
END
close cursor_Latest
DEALLOCATE cursor_Latest
```

and its result is

```
SELECT * From #nsn
ID  Val1    VAl2
1|  A1  |   A2
2|  B1  |   B2-A1-A2
3|  C1  |   C2-B1-B2
4|  D1  |   D2-C1-C2
5|  E1  |   F2-D1-D2
```

But I am expecting result as below,

```
ID  Val1    VAl2
1|  A1  |   A2
2|  B1  |   B2-A1-A2
3|  C1  |   C2-B1-B2-A1-A2
4|  D1  |   D2-C1-C2-B1-B2-A1-A2
5|  E1  |   F2-D1-D2-C1-C2-B1-B2-A1-A2
```

So is there any thing wrong in this code? or 
does Cursor has any record store thing because it is not getting latest updated values of new row.

Advance Thanks for Help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your expected result you should try something like below,

```
DECLARE @ID       INT
       ,@Val1     VARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@Val2     VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE cursor_Latest CURSOR  
FOR
    SELECT ID,Val1,Val2 FROM   #nsn
    ORDER BY 1 ASC

OPEN cursor_Latest
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_Latest INTO  @ID , @Val1 ,@Val2
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS<>-1)
BEGIN
    IF @ID=1
    BEGIN
        UPDATE #nsn
        SET    Val2     = Val2+'-'+@Val1+'-'+@Val2
        WHERE  ID       = @ID+1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE #nsn
        SET    Val2   = Val2+'-'+@Val1+'-'+@Val2+'-'+( SELECT Val1+'-'+Val2 FROM   #nsn WHERE  ID     = @ID-1)
        WHERE  ID                = @ID+1
    END 

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_Latest INTO @ID , @Val1 ,@Val2
END
CLOSE cursor_Latest
DEALLOCATE cursor_Latest

SELECT * FROM   #nsn
DROP TABLE  #nsn
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/004b4/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the "DYNAMIC" option in the cursor declare.

```
DECLARE cursor_Latest CURSOR DYNAMIC
```

Books online says it:
    "Defines a cursor that reflects all data changes made to the rows in its result set as you scroll around the cursor. The data values, order, and membership of the rows can change on each fetch."

in other words, the data will be fetched again for each fetch and it will reflect the change that was just made. therefore VAL2 will get the proper concatenation that you want.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it is not working. It is giving same output. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a cursor using `for xml` to concatenate the values in a correlated sub query.

```
update N1
set Val2 = (
           select case when N1.ID = N2.ID then '' else '-' + N2.Val1 end + '-' + N2.Val2
           from #nsn as N2
           where N1.ID >= N2.ID
           order by N2.ID desc
           for xml path(''), type
           ).value('substring(text()[1], 2)', 'varchar(max)')
from #nsn as N1
```

This does a triangular self join so if you have a lot of rows the cursor version might be the faster option. Try and find out.

Comment: Thanks, but I am having some different logic and calculation process in Cursor block and based on that I am updating this table row.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #nsn (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),Val1 Varchar(MAx),Val2 Varchar(MAx)) 

INSERT INTO #nsn(Val1,VAl2) select 'A1','A2'
INSERT INTO #nsn(Val1,VAl2) select 'B1','B2'
INSERT INTO #nsn(Val1,VAl2) select 'C1','C2'
INSERT INTO #nsn(Val1,VAl2) select 'D1','D2'
INSERT INTO #nsn(Val1,VAl2) select 'E1','F2'

DECLARE  @ID INT 
        ,@Val1 Varchar(MAx)
        ,@Val2 Varchar(MAx)
        ,@v1 Varchar(MAx)
        ,@v2 Varchar(MAx)
        ,@t Varchar(MAx),@val varchar(max)
        set @ID=1 


while @ID<=(select count(*) from #nsn)
begin
select @v1=val1,@v2=val2 from #nsn where ID=@ID
select @Val1=val1,@Val2=val2 from #nsn where id=@ID+1
update #nsn set val2= case when @val is not null then  @Val2+'-'+@v1+'-'+@val else @Val2+'-'+@v1+'-'+@v2  end  where id=@ID+1
select  @val=@Val2+'-'+@v1+'-'+@v2
set @ID=@ID+1
end
SELECT * From #nsn
```

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE  @ID INT ,@Val1 Varchar(MAx),@Val2 Varchar(MAx) ,@v1 Varchar(MAx)
        ,@v2 Varchar(MAx),@t Varchar(MAx),@val varchar(max)
set @ID=1 

while @ID<=(select count(*) from #nsn)

begin

select @v1=val1,@v2=val2 from #nsn where ID=@ID

select @Val1=val1,@Val2=val2 from #nsn where id=@ID+1

update #nsn set val2= case when @val is not null then  @Val2+'-'+@v1+'-'+@val else @Val2+'-'+@v1+'-'+@v2  end  where id=@ID+1

select  @val=@Val2+'-'+@v1+'-'+@v2

set @ID=@ID+1

end

SELECT * From #nsn